# Mi programa no encuentra el archivo que le doy a pesar de que sí exista

Tags: java

Al momento de crear el archivo, sí lo hace, pero cuando lo quiero leer, resulta que el archivo no lo encuentra a pesar que tiene el mismo nombre que el de crear porque es una variable.

```
public class AgregarEmpleado extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

    // componentes
    JLabel lbTitulo;
    JLabel lbIdentificador;
    JTextField tfIdentificador;
    JLabel lbNombre;
    JTextField tfNombre;
    JLabel lbTituloDireccion;
    JLabel lbCalle;
    JTextField tfCalle;
    JLabel lbNumero;
    JTextField tfNumero;
    JLabel lbColonia;
    JTextField tfColonia;
    JLabel lbFechaNacimiento;
    JTextField tfFechaNacimiento;
    JLabel lbGenero;
    JComboBox cbGenero;
    String[] generos; // info del comboBox
    JLabel lbSalario;
    JTextField tfSalario;
    JLabel lbTituloUsuario;
    JTextField tfTituloUsuario;
    JLabel lbUsuario;
    JTextField tfUsuario;
    JLabel lbContrasena;
    JTextField tfContrasena;
    JButton btGuardar;
    JButton btRegresar;    
    ArrayList<EmpleadoClase> empleadoArchivo;

    private final String ARCHIVO_LOGIN = "archivo.txt";     

    public AgregarEmpleado() {
        empleadoArchivo = new ArrayList<EmpleadoClase>();
        this.setTitle("Agregar Empleado");
        this.setSize(700, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        inicializarComponentes();
    }

    public void inicializarComponentes() {

        lbTitulo = new JLabel("Agregar Empleado");
        lbTitulo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbTitulo.setFont(new Font("Time New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lbTitulo.setBounds(200, 15, 300, 25);
        this.add(lbTitulo);

        // fila 1
        lbIdentificador = new JLabel("Idenficador");
        lbIdentificador.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbIdentificador.setBounds(75, 60, 100, 25);
        this.add(lbIdentificador);

        tfIdentificador = new JTextField();
        tfIdentificador.setBounds(75, 90, 100, 25);
        this.add(tfIdentificador);

        lbNombre = new JLabel("Nombre");
        lbNombre.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbNombre.setBounds(205, 60, 250, 25);
        this.add(lbNombre);

        tfNombre = new JTextField();
        tfNombre.setBounds(205, 90, 250, 25);
        this.add(tfNombre);

        lbFechaNacimiento = new JLabel("Fecha de Nacimiento");
        lbFechaNacimiento.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbFechaNacimiento.setBounds(475, 60, 150, 25);
        this.add(lbFechaNacimiento);

        tfFechaNacimiento = new JTextField();
        tfFechaNacimiento.setBounds(475, 90, 150, 25);
        this.add(tfFechaNacimiento);

        // fila 2
        lbGenero = new JLabel("Genero");
        lbGenero.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbGenero.setBounds(150, 125, 150, 25);
        this.add(lbGenero);

        cargarDatosArreglo();
        cbGenero = new JComboBox<String>(generos);
        cbGenero.setBounds(150, 155, 150, 25);
        cbGenero.addItemListener(this);
        this.add(cbGenero);

        lbSalario = new JLabel("Salario");
        lbSalario.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbSalario.setBounds(400, 125, 150, 25);
        this.add(lbSalario);

        tfSalario = new JTextField();
        tfSalario.setBounds(400, 155, 150, 25);
        this.add(tfSalario);

        // fila3
        lbCalle = new JLabel("Calle");
        lbCalle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbCalle.setBounds(75, 190, 100, 25);
        this.add(lbCalle);

        tfCalle = new JTextField();
        tfCalle.setBounds(75, 220, 100, 25);
        this.add(tfCalle);

        lbColonia = new JLabel("Colonia");
        lbColonia.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbColonia.setBounds(205, 190, 250, 25);
        this.add(lbColonia);

        tfColonia = new JTextField();
        tfColonia.setBounds(205, 220, 250, 25);
        this.add(tfColonia);

        lbNumero = new JLabel("Numero del Hogar");
        lbNumero.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbNumero.setBounds(475, 190, 150, 25);
        this.add(lbNumero);

        tfNumero = new JTextField();
        tfNumero.setBounds(475, 220, 150, 25);
        this.add(tfNumero);

        // fila 4
        lbUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario");
        lbUsuario.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbUsuario.setBounds(150, 255, 150, 25);
        this.add(lbUsuario);

        tfUsuario = new JTextField();
        tfUsuario.setBounds(150, 285, 150, 25);
        this.add(tfUsuario);

        lbContrasena = new JLabel("Contraseña");
        lbContrasena.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lbContrasena.setBounds(400, 255, 150, 25);
        this.add(lbContrasena);

        tfContrasena = new JTextField();
        tfContrasena.setBounds(400, 285, 150, 25);
        this.add(tfContrasena);

        // botones
        btRegresar = new JButton("Regresar");
        btRegresar.setBounds(175, 355, 100, 25);
        btRegresar.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btRegresar);

        btGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
        btGuardar.setBounds(425, 355, 100, 25);
        btGuardar.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(btGuardar);

    }

    private void cargarDatosArreglo() {
        generos = new String[] {
                "--------------",
                "Masculino",
                "Femenino"
        };
    }
```

Estos son mis eventos:

```
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
        int posicion = cbGenero.getSelectedIndex();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource().equals(btGuardar)){
            guardarInformacionEmpleado();            
            vaciarCuadros();
        } else if (ae.getSource().equals(btRegresar)) {
            Empleado empleado = new Empleado();
            this.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Guardo los datos de mi jtextfield que obtuve:

```
    private void guardarInformacionEmpleado() {
        
        String id;
        String name;
        String date;
        String gene;
        String sal;
        String calle;
        String colonia;
        String numero;
        String usuarioB;
        String password;

        System.out.println("Guarda infromación");
        id = tfIdentificador.getText();
        name = tfNombre.getText();
        date = tfFechaNacimiento.getText();
        int posicio = cbGenero.getSelectedIndex();
        gene = generos[posicio];
        sal = tfSalario.getText();
        calle = tfCalle.getText();
        colonia = tfColonia.getText();
        numero = tfNumero.getText();
        usuarioB = tfUsuario.getText();
        password = tfContrasena.getText();

        System.out.println("guarda objeto");
        EmpleadoClase empleado = new EmpleadoClase(id, name, date, gene, sal, calle, colonia, numero, usuarioB, password);
        System.out.println("termina de guardas y se agrega");
        agregarColeccion(empleado);        
        System.out.println(empleado.toString());

    }
    
    private void agregarColeccion(EmpleadoClase empleado) {
        System.out.println("entre a agreación");        
                
        System.out.println("lee el archivo");
        leerArchivo();        
        System.out.println("termina de leer y se combierte colección a texto");
        String datos = conviertirColeccionATexto();
        escribirArchivo(datos);

        System.out.println("Escribio");
    }

    private void vaciarCuadros() {        

        tfIdentificador.setText("");
        tfNombre.setText("");
        tfFechaNacimiento.setText("");
        cbGenero.setSelectedIndex(0);
        tfSalario.setText("");
        tfCalle.setText("");
        tfColonia.setText("");
        tfNumero.setText("");
        tfUsuario.setText("");
        tfContrasena.setText("");

    }

    private void imprimirArray(){
        String datos = ""; 
        for(int i=0; i<empleadoArchivo.size(); i++){
            EmpleadoClase empleado = empleadoArchivo.get(i);
            datos += empleado.getNombre() + empleado.getIdentidicador() + empleado.getNumeroCasa();
            
            if(i != empleadoArchivo.size()-1){
                datos += "\n";                
            }   

        }
    }
```

//métodos para archivo

Aquí se crea y se escribe sobre el archivo, esto sí lo hace de buena manera:

```
    private void escribirArchivo(String datos){         
        try{                        
            File file = new File(ARCHIVO_LOGIN);        
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);        
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);        
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            System.out.println("nuevo: " + datos);
        
            pw.write(datos);            
            pw.close();            
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("Escribio");
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("El archivo no se puede manipular...");
        }
    }
```

Aquí es donde se supone que debería leer el archivo, pero no lo encuentra y me manda a la exception de que no se pudo localizar:

```
    private void leerArchivo(){    
        System.out.println("entra a leer");    
        System.out.println("limpia");
        empleadoArchivo.clear(); 
        System.out.println("termina de limpiar");
        try{             
            FileReader fl = new FileReader(ARCHIVO_LOGIN); 
            BufferedReader bl = new BufferedReader(fl);                     

            String contenidoArchivo =""; 

            System.out.println("entra al while");
            while((contenidoArchivo = bl.readLine()) != null ){                
                EmpleadoClase usuario = convertirTextoAEmpleado(contenidoArchivo);                
                System.out.println("convierte texto");
                empleadoArchivo.add(usuario); 
                System.out.println("Agrega");
            }            
            bl.close(); 
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("Error al cargar el archivo: "+ex.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Error al leer o cerrar el archivo: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
**combierto el texto obtenido en una coleccioón**


    private EmpleadoClase convertirTextoAEmpleado(String texto){                        
        String[] elementosTexto = texto.split(","); 
               
        EmpleadoClase usuarioLectura = new EmpleadoClase();                 
        usuarioLectura.setIdentificador(elementosTexto[0]);        
        usuarioLectura.setNombre(elementosTexto[1]);        
        usuarioLectura.setFechaNacimiento(elementosTexto[2]);
        usuarioLectura.setGenero(elementosTexto[3]);
        usuarioLectura.setSalario(elementosTexto[4]);               
        usuarioLectura.setCalle(elementosTexto[5]);    
        usuarioLectura.setColonia(elementosTexto[6]);  
        usuarioLectura.setNumeroCasa(elementosTexto[7]);          
        usuarioLectura.setUsuario(elementosTexto[8]);        
        usuarioLectura.setPassword(elementosTexto[9]);
                
        return usuarioLectura; 
    }

    private String conviertirColeccionATexto(){
        String datos = "";
        for(int i=0; i < empleadoArchivo.size(); i++){
            EmpleadoClase usuarioCopia = empleadoArchivo.get(i);          
            datos += usuarioCopia.getIdentidicador()+","+usuarioCopia.getNombre()+","+usuarioCopia.getFechaNacimiento()+","+usuarioCopia.getGenero()+","+usuarioCopia.getSalario()+","+usuarioCopia.getCalle()+","+usuarioCopia.getColonia()+","+usuarioCopia.getNumeroCasa()+","+usuarioCopia.getUsuario()+","+usuarioCopia.getPassword();
            if(i != empleadoArchivo.size()-1){
                datos += "\n";                
            }            
        }
        return datos;
    }   
}
```

Comment: No sé si este es el problema, no leí el código completo, pero puedo ver que solo está trabajando con el NOMBRE del archivo, y es un error común trabajar solo con el nombre del archivo, usted tiene que usar una ruta, elija una carpeta en su sistema para que sea la ubicación predeterminada de su archivo, asegúrese de que esta carpeta esté en su "entorno de usuario" para que la JVM tenga acceso para leer y escribir, y use una ruta completa + nombre siempre que trabajas con archivos externos, Utilice siempre "C:\\carpeta\\carpeta\\archivo.txt" y evite siempre que sea posible sólo "archivo.txt"

Comment: Si es posible podrias poner solo el codigo de la funcion EscribirArchivo(), ya que es complicado comprender todo tu codigo, cuando tu problema solo se enfoca en una cosa.